# Is it possible for pandas use read_csv for several files

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is it possible to use pandas read_csv function to read simultaneously several files each one into separate dataframe?

Comment: NO, It cant do that. Show your code.

Comment: Try something like this: `dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `os` module to iterate over the file strings in the directory you are interested in (Assuming there are only csv files there) then add them to a list.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\tempdata"):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(i))

print df_list[0]
print df_list[1]
```

Output:

```
  Name Name2  Time
0  NaN   NaN     1
1  NaN   NaN     2
2   G     G      3

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  2  3
2  3  2  3
```